# How to combine two tables with different Primary Keys by multiple columns ideally HASH

Tags: sql, hash, hashtable, hashcode

I have two tables of world countries Independence Day and I wanted to combine them into one table with a distinct id, but they are using different Primary keys, any suggestions will be appreciated.
Summary of request: How to combine two tables with different Primary Keys but the other fields in common and removing duplicate fields ideally Hash Match and removing duplicates

Expected Results this will include all the unique countries in both tables, please one table may have more countries and we want to make sure we take all the distinct countries from each table. Ideally, the solution will be likely to be of like Hash Match operator in SQL which implements several different logical operations that all use an in-memory hash table for finding matching data. Many thanks in advance

The image of two tables which needs combining.

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why on earth did you edit this to remove the example data???

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `full join`:

```
select a.*, b.*    -- select the columns you want
from a full join
     b
     on a.country = b.country;
```

If you want to assign a new unique id use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by coalesce(a.country, b.country)) as new_id,
       a.*, b.*    -- select the columns you want
from a full join
     b
     on a.country = b.country;
```

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff, Much appreciated, for advice, ideally I want to combine using two columns as this will guarantee no duplicates as I want to use the same principle with I have a table with similar issue.